# On SQL Server is it possible to set a group of columns to null for a single row?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Say I have a table with 20 columns.
Is it possible to do something like this:

```
UPDATE Tbl SET (COLUMN1,COLUMN2,COLUMN4,COLUMN9) = null WHERE ID=4
```

or do i have to do as below?

```
UPDATE Tbl SET COLUMN1=NULL,COLUMN2=NULL,COLUMN4=NULL,COLUMN9=NUll WHERE ID=4
```

Thanks

Comment: You have to use the second. The first does not exist. Any basic SQL book or tutorial would have answered  this question.

Comment: If you have a humongous count of columns, you can use dynamic SQL

Comment: You are correct, Kenny!  Any basic SQL book would tell me to use the second.  I asked because I don't know everything and basic books don't cover everything by their nature.  I'll still upvote, though.  You did answer my question.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you have to do as below :

```
UPDATE Tbl SET COLUMN1=NULL,COLUMN2=NULL,COLUMN4=NULL,COLUMN9=NUll WHERE ID=4
```

This is sql syntax we cannot change it, but if you have many columns and you want to avoid write query/value for each columns you can create sql script dynamically and execute it, see this :

```
Declare @DynamicColumns NVARCHAR(MAX)
Declare @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @DynamicColumns ='Write here stuff to retrieve columns with value dynamically. e.g : Column1=value1,Column2=value1 '

SET @SQL = 'UPDATE Table1 SET '+@DynamicColumns+' WHERE ID=100'

EXEC(@SQL)
```

Comment: Thank you, Rajendra.  Appreciate the assist and alternate approach

Comment: still need to put column and value in this dynamic SQL, and it is over engineered

Comment: @LONG : Yeah, still need to put column and value in this dynamic sql, but as i mention if there are many columns needs to write value for update then we can you dynamic sql, and to preapar DynamicColumns we can use CURSOR / SELECT.

Comment: @Rajendra, better to open the script as `update to`, just put in value and delete unrelated columns

Comment: @LONG : Yeah you are write when there is just simple update statement for minimum columns, but this thread is to explore how to minimize writing scripts if there are many columns. and dynamic script is always better i think,.. :)

Answer (score 1):

This sintax   (not fake tuple  to  single value)

```
 UPDATE Tbl 
 SET COLUMN1 = null,
     COLUMN2 = null,
     COLUMN4 = null,
     COLUMN9  = null 
 WHERE ID=4
```